Sending users to correct OAuth login page for multitenant client - Microsoft OneDrive FilePicker 7.2
I am trying to set up OneDrive FilePicker 7.2 in a way that when users choose to connect their personal accounts, they are taken to signup.live.com(or something similar) where you can only sign in with personal accounts) and to login.microsoftonline.com/organizations(or something similar) where they can only use a work/school account when they choose to connect their work account.
I know I can do the first part by setting the endpointHint to api.onedrive.com but then the token returned is for that endpoint and I need to use graph to fetch user details. So that is not an option for me. For the second part, I could not figure out a way at all.
One possible solution could be to use two different applications, one allowing authentication with personal accounts only and the other with work accounts but this creates other problems.
Has anyone encountered this/knows a way around ?

